# Difficulties Consuming SOAP API in C#

Tags: c#, xml, soap

A company I'm working with offers a SOAP API to automate use of their service.

The API documentation says "API is nearly universally
acceptable: SOAP clients are available for PHP, PERL, Python und Java.
However, clients have experienced challenges when integrating into C#
environments"

When I make SOAP calls from SoapUI, I can successfully authenticate with the API. However, when I link the WSDL file as a Service Reference in C# in Visual Studio, I get a response from the API, but authentication always fails.

The authentication operation takes 3 parameters:

```
<part name="salt" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="token" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="budgetID" type="xsd:string"/>
```

Where `salt` is a random letter or number, `token` is a hash of `salt` and my password, and `budgetID` is a unique identifier for my account.

SoapUI makes the following call and has the exact result I want:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:urn="urn:loginService">
      <soapenv:Header/>
      <soapenv:Body>
         <urn:doLogin soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            <salt xsi:type="xsd:string">12</salt>
            <token xsi:type="xsd:string">ae4894ac690d70b0a3ebf27763</token>
            <budgetID xsi:type="xsd:string">6e080f339657ce5be68059bec9</budgetID>
         </urn:doLogin>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

However, when I make a similar call in C# using the linked Service Reference, using code like below, I get a response from the API but it fails to authenticate:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int salt = rnd.Next(1, 10000);
string token;
string budgetKey = "XXX";
using(MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
{
    token GetMD5Hash(md5Hash, (salt + txtBudgetPassword.Password).ToString());
}

//Instantiate the web services client created by my Service Reference
loginServicePortClient login = new loginServicePortClient();
Console.Write(login.doLogin(salt, token.ToString(), budgetKey));
```

Is there some known issue with the .NET/C# SOAP client that's keeping the exact same credentials from working in this client? I know it's not an issue with the MD5 hash because the output of that function is what I used to successfully test the call in SoapUI.

I just have a hard time believing that there's no way to consume this API in C#/.NET.

The API documentation is available [here](https://www.textbroker.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/API_Documentation_EN_v1.3.6.pdf).

EDIT: Here are the headers from the SoapUI and C# calls:

SoapUI:

```
POST /Budget/loginService.php HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "urn:loginService#loginService#doLogin"
Content-Length: 609
Host: api.textbroker.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

C#:

```
CONNECT api.textbroker.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.textbroker.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Comment: Best way of debugging issues like this is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Capture good results with SoapUi and compare to c# results.  Look at the http headers and compare good and bad,  The issue usually can be solved by adding missing headers to the c# code.

Comment: I've added the raw headers from both requests to the original post. Does anything jump out as being missing from the C# one? I'm not super familiar with this stuff and I don't know how to edit the headers in the C# request.

Comment: `However, when I make a similar call in C# using the linked Service Reference, using code like below:` It feels like we are missing the end of that sentence.

Comment: All the difference are important.  First standard port number for http is 80 (or 8080).  You are using 443 which is https (secure).  Then you are using http 1.1 (chunk mode) which doesn't work with httprequest.  Normally I have to force httprequest to use 1.0 (stream mode).  Chunk mode requires a next chunk message to be sent and I have not found way of sending next chunk.  Then in c# you need to handle the gzip mode.  An finally the Content-Type is wrong.

Comment: @jdweng so the WSDL address provided by the API is an HTTPS address. Should I still be trying to do this over HTTP?

Comment: The document on page 9 says : clients have experienced challenges when integrating into C# environments.  Doesn't mean it can't be done.  There are plenty of link on web to specify how to handle gzip and add Content-Type and User-Agent to a c# application.  I'm not sure why you are using port 443 where Soap isn't using port 443.  You are using Http (not HTTPS uses port 443) so I would leave port number off unless the documentation says to use 443.  If you do not understand something let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say what is happening but I would start by using fiddler to inspect the soap packet on it's way to the API this will show you if it is malformed or if there is another issue.

Comment: When I use Fiddler to inspect the packet, and open the XML tab, I get `Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1` and no XML is displayed. Is there a different tab I can paste the output of to provide useful information?

Comment: Hi Nathan, we might be closing in on your issue ;-). have a look at the raw tab you should be able to see the soap packet and compare it to the valid example.